# Change value on duplicated rows using Pyspark, keeping the first record as is

Tags: pyspark

how can I change the column status value on rows that contains duplicate records on specific columns, and keep the first one(with the lower id) as A, for example:

logic:

- if the account_id and user_id already exists the status is E, the first record(lower id) is A
- if the user_id exists and the account_id is different the status is I, the first record(lower id) is A

input sample:

| id | account_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | a | 1 |
| 3 | b | 1 |
| 4 | c | 2 |
| 5 | c | 2 |
| 6 | c | 2 |
| 7 | d | 3 |
| 8 | d | 3 |
| 9 | e | 3 |

output sample

| id | account_id | user_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | A |
| 2 | a | 1 | E |
| 3 | b | 1 | I |
| 4 | c | 2 | A |
| 5 | c | 2 | E |
| 6 | c | 2 | E |
| 7 | d | 3 | A |
| 8 | d | 3 | E |
| 9 | e | 3 | I |

I think I need to group into multiple datasets and join it back, compare and change the values, I think I'm overthinking, help?
Thanks!!

Thank you

Comment: I'm a bit confused when reading your question. Do you mind update it with **example input** and **expected output**? I'm not sure your _source data sample_ is input or output

Comment: Added clarification on input and output, thanks for point that out

Answer (score 0):

Two window functions would help you to determine the duplications and rank them.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
    # Distinguishes between "first occurrence" vs "2nd occurrence" and so on
    .withColumn('rank', F.rank().over(W.partitionBy('account_id', 'user_id').orderBy('id')))
    
    # Detecting if there is no duplication per pair of 'account_id' and 'user_id'
    .withColumn('count', F.count('*').over(W.partitionBy('account_id', 'user_id')))
    
    # building status based on conditions
    .withColumn('status', F
        .when(F.col('count') == 1, 'I') # if there is only one record, status is 'I'
        .when(F.col('rank') == 1, 'A')  # if there is more than one record, the first occurrence is 'A'
        .otherwise('E')                 # finally, the other occurrences are 'E'
    )
    .orderBy('id')
    .show()
)

# Output
# +---+----------+-------+----+-----+------+
# | id|account_id|user_id|rank|count|status|
# +---+----------+-------+----+-----+------+
# |  1|         a|      1|   1|    2|     A|
# |  2|         a|      1|   2|    2|     E|
# |  3|         b|      1|   1|    1|     I|
# |  4|         c|      2|   1|    3|     A|
# |  5|         c|      2|   2|    3|     E|
# |  6|         c|      2|   3|    3|     E|
# |  7|         d|      3|   1|    2|     A|
# |  8|         d|      3|   2|    2|     E|
# |  9|         e|      3|   1|    1|     I|
# +---+----------+-------+----+-----+------+
```